# how use *.acv a file for tone curve in gpuimage in android?

Tags: android, filter, photoshop, gpuimage

I have implemented in android the gpuimage library, but dont exist one method for read *.acv.

i use  android and gpuimage library.

I need use the curve tone of the files in *.acv for my function.

```
GPUImageFilter filter = new GPUImageFilter();

  case 1: {

  filter = new GPUImageToneCurveFilter();
                break;}
```

Comment: Perhaps reading the code for that class would help: https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/blob/master/library/src/jp/co/cyberagent/android/gpuimage/GPUImageToneCurveFilter.java

Comment: With setFromCurveFileInputStream() ?
My file is : 02.acv for example, and i need take that curveTone for use in filter.
how pick that file from directory raw.

Answer (score 3):

Problem Solved!

how said BradLarsson, the response is in library, thanks!

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tone_cuver_sample);

      case 1: {

           filter = new GPUImageToneCurveFilter();
           ((GPUImageToneCurveFilter) filter).setFromCurveFileInputStream(in);  
           break;
      }
```

Comment: Could you please upload the whole test project to [Github](https://github.com/) so that we can learn it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also easy to impalement

//read image

```
AssetManager as = getAssets ();  
InputStream is =  null ;  
Bitmap Bitmap =  null ;  
try  {  
is = as.open ( "dog.jpg" );  
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream (is);  
is.close ();  
}  catch  (IOException e) {  
Log.e ( "MainActivity" ,  "Error" );  
}
```

// Read Photoshop files of acv

```
GPUImageToneCurveFilter filter =  new  GPUImageToneCurveFilter ();  
try  {  
is = as.open ( "tone_curve.acv" );  
filter.setFromCurveFileInputStream (is);  
is.close ();  
}  catch  (IOException e) {  
Log.e ( "MainActivity" ,  "Error" );  
}  

// Use GPUImage processed image  
GPUImage gpuImage =  new  GPUImage (self);  
gpuImage.setImage (bitmap);  
gpuImage.setFilter (filter);  
bitmap = gpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied ();  

// Later in the ImageView image display processing  
ImageView View =  new  ImageView (self);  
view.setImageBitmap (bitmap);  
setContentView (view);
```

Comment: Could you please upload the whole test project to Github so that we can learn it.